# Проблемы с компиляцией библиотеки libnet для iOS7

Tags: c, ios, iphone, objective-c, сеть

Я пытаюсь собрать libnet 1.1.7 для использования его в проекте для iOS7. Но проблема в том, что штатными средствами (export CFLAGS=-m32, configure, make и make install) собирается libnet.dylib для OS X. И если такую libnet.dylib использовать в iOS проекте, то линкер начинает законно ругаться:

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/usr/local/lib/libnet.dylib' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Как можно сделать сборку libnet конкретно для iOS или, возможно, ее уже кто-то делал до меня (в этом случае буду благодарен за ссылку) .

P.S. Я использую Xcode 5.0.1 и OS X 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще странно, потому как iOS Simulator это тот же самый OS X.
Судя по всему, про сборке он по умолчанию выбирает ту target architecture, на которой идёт сборка (в вашем случае — i386, так как вы дополнительно указываете `-m32`), а так же SDK для данной платформы.

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19727843) на SO есть хорошая подборка флагов для сборки как для iOS Simulator, так и для реального устройства + объединение их в один fat executable для удобства.

Comment: Я пересобрал libnet c флагами, которые вы предложили, теперь компиляция iOS проекта проходит без ошибок и с запуском в эмуляторе проблем тоже нет. Благодарствую за помощь.